# Excel basic how to highlight lines where cell A and B are not equal?

Tags: excel, basic

i was wondering if its possible (using typical excel tools) to mark all lines in document providing that two chosen cells, in this line, are different. If build-in tools wont make it i suppose i would have to write basic script to do it for me. In that case any advice welcome :) Any information i managed to find is about condition formatting, but its not suffice to do it in the way in need it.
It should be something like:
Check line 1 if cell A1 is not equal to cell B1, highlight whole line and step to the next line else step to the next line.

Comment: That would be perfectly possible through conditional formatting. Not sure about the information you found, but it will suffice.

Comment: Hello JvdV. Thank You for your answer. Indeed conditionalt formatting was sufficient to do what i wanted to achieve. Feel little embarassed when i saw how easy it was :/